# Passing variables between View Controllers using a segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, xcode6

I use Swift and Xcode 6 and  would like to pass a variable from one View Controller to another using a Segue.

I have created a segue called 'MainToTimer' which is trigger once button is pressed. I would like to be able to use the variable called 'Duration' on the second View Controller.

Is it possible to pass multiple variables and constants?

What code do I need associated to each View Controller?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass data between view controllers in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215476/how-do-you-pass-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift)

Answer (score 44):

First, setup property/properties to hold your variables in your second view controller (destination).

```
class YourSecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var duration:Double?
}
```

Then have your button trigger your custom segue. Use your variable ('duration') as the argument for sender.

```
class YourFirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MainToTimer", sender: duration)
    }
}
```

Finally, pass this sender data by overriding the prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "MainToTimer") {
        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as YourSecondViewController
        let duration = sender as Double
        secondViewController.duration = duration
    }
}
```

Yes, it is also possible to pass multiple variables and constants, again using the 'sender' parameter of prepareForSegue. If you have multiple data you want to pass in, put them in an array and make that array the sender.

**SWIFT 3**
From Swift 3, the method `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)` has changed to `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

Comment: OK ... I see how this works ... I might even use it ... but I have a bad feeling since this is not really what the sender argument was designed for. Usually I find out later there why you shouldn't do this, but I can't think of anything right now.

Comment: Where do I put the override function? Which class, and is it before I perform the segue function?

Answer (score 6):

In the first `ViewController` place this (for modal segue):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let theDestination = (segue.destinationViewController as ViewController2)
    theDestination.Duration2 = Duration
}
```

Change `ViewController2` to the name of the second `ViewController`.  In `ViewController2` create a class variable:

```
var Duration2 = (whatever the type - UInt8 I guess for time)
```

That's it.  You will have in the value of `Duration2` the value of `Duration` from the first `ViewController`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to incorporate your suggestion and have received an error. (1) in line self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MainToTimer", sender Duration) I receive an error saying Type 'Duration' does not conform to protocol 'Any Object'   (2)in line theDestination.Duration2 = Duration I receive an error - Expected member name or constructor call after type name.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Later version of Xcode 6 changed the method.  I have updated it above and it should work fine now.

Comment: `if (segue.identifier = "MainToTimer") {` needs to be `if (segue.identifier == "MainToTimer") {`

ur comparing, not assigning