# Change static variable

Tags: swift, static, global-variables

im new in swift. I'd like to ask u if i go the right way.

I have something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    struct myVars {
        var static short_text = ""
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadData()
        println(short_text)
    }

    func loadData() {
         myVars.short_text = "Hello world!"
    }
}
```

This code works. I have "Hello world!" string in the variable and i can print it. But iam asking you if this is a good and clear way to redefine static var? I do it because i want to work with this variable across the code.

Thank you for your answers.

PS: The final methods are much more difficult. This is shorted code for example only.

Comment: thank you! I'm not so good in english to describe it as well as i'd like to do. But simply: I load a lot of data in function loadData and i need to use that data in another functions without calling loadData again. Because data was once loaded. Its better to use internal var and loose struct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you share data between view controllers and other objects in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift)

Comment: (a) i mean i use internal var short_text="" and its not inside struct. Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to make the variable for this instance of `ViewController` accessible to other classes (i.e. other view controllers), then you don't have to use `static`. You only need to use `static` if it is critical to make the property accessible across multiple instances of that class. I don't think that's what you intended here.

If the intent is to pass data between the view controllers, I'd suggest you refer to:

- [How do you share data between view controllers and other objects in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift)
- [How do you pass data between view controllers in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25215476/1271826)

If you search for "pass data between view controllers", you'll find lots of other similar links.

Bottom line, the use of `static` is possible, but probably not what you intended.

---

Two side notes:

1. You are using a `static` within a `struct`. Swift 1.2 obviates the need for that pattern. If you really need `static` (and I don't think you need it here), you can just declare your variable as `static` and eliminate the `struct`:

   ```
   static var shortText = ""
   ```
2. I don't think your use of `struct` meant to open the "by-value vs by-reference" discussion, but if you did, I might refer you to WWDC 2015 video [Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=414).