# UIImageView as a SubView of UIView in my UIViewController Class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I have a `UIViewController` in which I added a `UIView`. In that `UIView` I added some `UIImageView`s through programming. What I need is that when I click the image it shows in a new `UIViewController`.

```
ViewController : UIViewController {
    myUIview[[imageview]  [ ]  [  ]  [  ]  [  ] ]
}
```

Comment: in UIView class make delegate protocol and if you click image send info to delegate (your UIViewController) about that and do whatever you want

Comment: can you please explain through code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to segue to another ViewController when your users press on an UIImageView. So here is my solution using an UITapGestureRecognizer (put this code in viewDidLoad):

```
yourImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let yourImageTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.test(_ :)))
yourImageTapGesture.delegate = self
yourImageTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
yourImageView.addGestureRecognizer(yourImageTapGesture)
```

Then in your ViewController you have to make the function test, which is triggered when somebody taps on your UIImageView:

```
func test(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueName",sender: self)
}
```

**Important:** "YourSegueName" is the Identifier of your Segue in your Storyboard. You can set it by clicking on your Segue:

[image]

Keep in my mind that your ViewController needs to inherit from one more class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {...}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation but you misunderstood one part. I have multiple imageviews in my uiview. so what i want is that when i click first image in my uiview then image show up in new view controller. Keep in mind that i have made imageViews through programming.

Comment: @SaadUllah I suggest you pass the UIImageView with the segue. Keep my code and add the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25215574/6597361

Comment: Is your code able to identify that which image i want to pick. Consider I have 4 images in my UIView

Comment: Add something like `for image in yourUIImageViewArray { ... }` and add a variable there with the right image, which should be passed to the other VC