# passing variables to NSView

Tags: macos, class, swift3

I'm trying to pass the contents of an array to an NSView to display rectangles x positions.
I have set up a version using random numbers and a button and reduced the code to a minimum so hopefully it's more readable . I  have tried creating the array as a Global Variable. I have also tried reversing the code from this answer.[Pass data between view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215476/how-do-you-pass-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift).I have inserted a comment: *"This is what I would like to achieve"* which explain what i'm trying to achieve.
I'm hoping someone might help ? thanks

Swift 3 Xcode 8.1 OSX Mac OS not iOS

```
//
//  MainWindowController.swift

import Cocoa
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: NSView!
    var myArray = [Int]()
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        //just for testing
        for i in 0..<6{
            myArray.append(i*10)
        }
    }//EO Overide

    //just for testing
    @IBAction func myButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        myFunc()
    }

    func myFunc(){
        for i in 0..<6{
            let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
            myArray[i]=diceRoll * 10
        }

        myView.needsDisplay = true

    }//EO myFunc
}//EnD oF thE wORld



class myGUI: NSView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {

        for i in..<6{
   let fromArray = myArray[i]
            let box1 = NSMakeRect(CGFloat(fromArray),0,4,60)//This is what i want to do
            let box1Color = NSColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1.0)
            let box1Path: NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath(rect: box1)
            box1Color.set()
            box1Path.fill()

        }//EO For

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a strong reference to the subclass of `NSView` just add a property:

```
class myGUI: NSView {

    var xPosArray = [Int]()      

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        for xPos  in  xPosArray { // please avoid ugly C-style index based loops
           let box1 = NSMakeRect(CGFloat(xPos), 0, 4, 60)
    ...
```

and  simply set it in the view controller

```
func myFunc(){
    for i in 0..<6 {
        let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
        myArray[i]=diceRoll * 10
    }
    myView.xPosArray = myArray
    myView.needsDisplay = true
 }
```

Consider that class names are supposed to start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: I take note about class names and ugly loops I never knew that loop style existed (self taught) I am getting the error. "Value of type 'NSView' has no member 'array' " Thanks

Comment: In Interface Builder you have to set the class of the custom view to `myGUI`

Comment: I had already set the class of the view to myGUI still no luck

Comment: I know that part is working have tested it using a global variable set from myFunc

Comment: Additionally you have to change this line:  `@IBOutlet weak var myView: myGUI!`. A global variable is not recommended and not needed at all in this case.

Comment: I was only using a global variable to test the GUI was working. which it is .I have reposted the code with your additions but still get the Error as commented.

Comment: Yes you are correct but that line only worked when i changed all the other things you said. Great Answers

Comment: I have updated the original code so that it works tried to + this answer is useful but i don't have enough reputations

Comment: Please don't edit the question with the correct code, so nobody can follow the step from the issue to the solution. Probably you have enough reputation to accept the answer.

Comment: sorry changed it back to original