# I Want to pull a result from a Pickerview and put it in a label in another view controller in xcode with swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have done many things to do it but I got no answer 
I am using core data...
and All of a sudden the problem gets worst
so what should I do ? (I can give U my whole project to examine it better)

Comment: whats your problem?
Please describe it in detail.

Comment: Without a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**, your question is considered off-topic here, since questions seeking debugging help **must** include the relevant code and a description of the expected behaviour. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before including any code in the question and definitely don't include your whole project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic Step:

1) Get value from Picker :
=> use below datasource method

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
            // use the row to get the selected row from the picker view
            // using the row extract the value from your datasource (array[row])
            // Put code for add value on UILabel
}
```

2) Send it to another view controller

[How do you pass data between view controllers in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215476/how-do-you-pass-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift)

Comment: I think the best method would be: picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)

Comment: Yes but It will be returned Index and we can get value from the array.

Comment: Please don't post answers to such unclear questions. There is no possible way to provide a good answer when we have no idea what the actual issue is.

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo 

Thank U it helped me a lot

Comment: @Sergey Di Yes But it will return the index

Comment: Believe me I couldn't ask it so much clearer 
I wanted a output of picker view in another label in a whole another VC
and I am a beginner So that was the best shot of mine
@rmaddy