# Pass Array of URLs to another View Controller via Segue

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, segue

I have a single Window controller and 2 View Controllers.When the user clicks a button I need to open the second View Controller.I clicked and dragged a segue from the first view to the second view from a button.Now when the user clicks the Button the second View Controller opens up

[image]

Now I need to pass some data-Array of URLs from the first View Controller to the second.It seems that I need to override some function of the segue to achieve this

I have tried the following code from the answer related to IOS here 
[How do you pass data between view controllers in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215476/how-do-you-pass-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift)

Since the classes are different for OSX,many classes are undefined

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "YourSegueName") {
        //get a reference to the destination view controller
        let destinationVC:ViewControllerClass = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerClass

        //set properties on the destination view controller
        destinationVC.name = viewName
        //etc...
    }
}
```

So far I know how to override the segue preparation in OSX.I don't know how to identify the segue and pass the required data to the new ViewController.

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
}
```

Please advice.

Comment: I find several examples if I run a quick Google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nearly there, your code just needs some tweaks for MacOS.

Your prepare for segue method would look like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if (segue.identifier?.rawValue == "YourSegueName") {
    //get a reference to the destination view controller
    let destinationVC:MyViewController = segue.destinationController as! MyViewController

    //set properties on the destination view controller
    destinationVC.urls = [] //pass in urls here
  }
}
```

You can see there are a few adjustments for MacOS, `UIStoryboardSegue`->`NSStoryboardSegue`, `AnyObject`->`Any` (This should be `Any` now in iOS too), you'll need the `rawValue` of the `identifier`, `destination`->`destinationController`.

The `ViewControllerClass` mentioned in your code refers to a class that you create that subclasses `NSViewController`. I've created an example called `MyViewController`, just to show you what it could look like:

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {
  var urls:[URL] = [] {
    didSet(newValue) {
      //do something here
    }
  }
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

In the storyboard to make all of this work, you would need to do a few things:

1. Give the segue an identifier eg. "YourSegueName"
2. Give the second view controller a class identifier eg. MyViewController

I recommend you read a tutorial on this, for example, Ray Wenderlich's [MacOS View Controllers Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/153844/macos-view-controllers-tutorial).

Comment: Thanks a lot ... ☺️

Comment: Have updated to be relevant to passing in an array of URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the segue:

[image]

Select your segue in storyboard and give it a identifier name like in the image on top left.

Now you can access the segue identifier via:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goToFilterViewController") {

        let destinationVC: YourViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! YourViewController

        //set properties on the destination view controller
        destinationVC.yourArray = array

        ...
    }
}
```

And your ViewController should be like this:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    //your array should be a optional in your ViewController
    var yourArray: [String]!

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... But my question refers to OSX...Not IOS